# Google Drive. Refresh authorization token while a file is uploading

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

What is the way to refresh authorization token while a large file is uploading to Google Drive?
For example: expiration time of the current authorization token is "06:00 AM". The file uploading started at "05:15 AM". So at "06:00 AM" the application get exception due authorization token is invalid.

I've tried to around the issue with the below source code, but it does not work.

```
/// <summary>
/// Uploads a file with a specified path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="startFolder">The start folder.</param>
/// <param name="path">The path of destination file.</param>
/// <param name="localFile">The local file to upload.</param>
/// <returns>The uploaded file.</returns>
private File GdUploadFile(File startFolder, string path, FileInfo localFile)
{
    if (startFolder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("startFolder");
    }

    if (localFile == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("localFile");
    }

    if (!localFile.Exists)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", localFile.FullName);
    }

    var config = GetConfiguration();

    if (config.TraceLog)
    {
        Destination.Logger.LogDebug(string.Format("{0} \tUpload file \"{1}\" to \"{2}\"", Destination.Name, localFile.FullName, path));
    }

    string pathToFile = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? localFile.Name : path;

    string remotePath = ExtractFilePath(pathToFile);
    var fileFolder = GdCreateFolderByPath(startFolder, remotePath);
    var fileName = ExtractFileName(pathToFile);

    DriveService service = GetDriveService();

    var body = new File
                   {
                       Title = fileName,
                       Description = "My File",
                       MimeType = BackupFileMimeType,
                       Kind = DriveFileKindType,
                       OriginalFilename = fileName,
                       FileExtension = localFile.Extension,
                       Parents = new List<ParentReference>
                                     {
                                         new ParentReference
                                             {
                                                 ETag = fileFolder.ETag,
                                                 Id = fileFolder.Id,
                                                 Kind = fileFolder.Kind
                                             }
                                     }
                   };

    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request;
    var source = new MediaFileSource(localFile.FullName, BackupFileMimeType);

    using (var fileStream = source.GetDataStream())
    {
        if (config.TraceLog)
        {
            Destination.Logger.LogDebug(string.Format("{0} \tUploading \"{1}\"...", Destination.Name, localFile.FullName));
        }

        request = service.Files.Insert(body, fileStream, body.MimeType);

        if (config.TraceLog)
        {
            int postedPercent = 0;

            request.ProgressChanged += p =>
                                           {
                                               var currentPercent = (int) (p.BytesSent/(double) source.ContentLength*100);

                                               if (currentPercent != postedPercent)
                                               {
                                                   string msg = string.Format("{0} \tPosted {1}% ({2} bytes)", Destination.Name,
                                                                              currentPercent, p.BytesSent);
                                                   Destination.Logger.LogDebug(msg);
                                                   postedPercent = currentPercent;
                                               }
                                           };
        }

        var connection = Destination.Connection as GoogleDriveDestinationConnection;
        Debug.Assert(connection != null, "connection != null");

        request.ProgressChanged += p =>
                                       {
                                           bool refreshAuth = connection.ForceRefreshAuthorization();
                                           var auth =
                                               request.Authenticator as
                                               Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>;

                                           if (auth != null && auth.State != null && refreshAuth)
                                           {
                                               var state = connection.AuthorizationState;
                                               auth.State.AccessToken = state.AccessToken;
                                               auth.State.AccessTokenExpirationUtc = state.AccessTokenExpirationUtc;
                                               auth.State.AccessTokenIssueDateUtc = state.AccessTokenIssueDateUtc;
                                               auth.State.Callback = state.Callback;
                                               auth.State.RefreshToken = state.RefreshToken;
                                               auth.State.SaveChanges();

                                               if (config.TraceLog)
                                               {
                                                   Destination.Logger.LogDebug("Authorization state for the upload request is updated");
                                               }

                                           }
                                       };

        request.ChunkSize = ChunkSize;
        request.Upload();

        if (config.TraceLog)
        {
            Destination.Logger.LogDebug(string.Format("{0} \t\"{1}\" uploaded", Destination.Name, localFile.FullName));
        }
    }

    return request.ResponseBody;
}
```

Comment: Just refresh the token before you start the file upload process if the token is due to expire within an hour.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good thought. I'm going to around this issue by this way.
But in this case a user cannot upload a file if it takes more time than one hour (uploading large file with low speed of internet connection).

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing  Resumable upload (https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable). Refresh the token when needed and continue the upload where you left off.

Comment: I'm already using ResumableUpload<TRequest> class. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Upload/ResumableUpload.cs

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a satisfactory solution to the problem of invalid authorization token.
So I have created my own open source lightweight library for working with files on Google Drive. The library invokes all REST functions directly and have full control over uploading or downloading processes. It resolves the problem by refreshing the authorization token every hour. The library is currently in use in thousands of installations of my company’s Sql Server backup product, it is very stable and has successfully resolved this problem. You can take the source code and examples from here: https://github.com/AlexeyVlg/Pranas.Net.Clouds